# Sed insists on doing partial matches

Tags: grep, sed, awk

Ok, consider this example file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat > example_file.txt <<EOL
group, , price
1, S_BRN_, 3.21
1, S_WBS_BRN_, 4.11
1, S_WBS_BRN, 1.22
2, S_BRN_WBS, 9.2
2, F_WBS_BRN_, 2.11
2, F_BRN_, 2.11
2, F_BRN_WBS_, 2.11
EOL
```

I want all lines that contain the string 'F_BRN_' or "S_BRN_'. I do the following sed:

```
sed -n '/S_BRN_\|F_BRN_/p' example_file.txt
```

and I get:

```
1, S_BRN_, 3.21
1, S_WBS_BRN_, 4.11
2, S_BRN_WBS, 9.2
2, F_WBS_BRN_, 2.11
2, F_BRN_, 2.11
2, F_BRN_WBS_, 2.11
```

my question is: how to prevent partial matches? For example F_WBS_BRN_ does not contain the substring F_BRN_, so it should not be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F_WB**S_BRN_** contains the substring S_BRN_ so *should* be returned by your expression.

If you want to match strings that *start* with either S_BRN_ or F_BRN_ you can enable extended regular expressions using the `-r` or `-E` switch and use a word boundary anchor

```
$ sed -rn '/\b(S_BRN_|F_BRN_)/p' example_file.txt
1, S_BRN_, 3.21
2, S_BRN_WBS, 9.2
2, F_BRN_, 2.11
2, F_BRN_WBS_, 2.11
```

or more simply

```
sed -rn '/\b[SF]_BRN_/p' example_file.txt
```

In your case, you could also match the space before S or F, however the word boundary anchor has the advantage of also matching where there is no specific preceding character to anchor to, such as at the start-of-line.

Alternatively (since you also tagged the question `awk`) you could match the second space-delimited field, and use a start-of-pattern anchor `^`:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^[SF]_BRN_/' example_file.txt
```